# Is there a way to force WebView link clicks to open externally?

Tags: react-native

I've got a `WebView` component that's loading static HTML content:

```
  <WebView
    style={{flex: 1}}
    html={content}
  />
```

The issue is, if someone taps a link, it opens in the app and I'd rather force it to use `Linking` to open in Safari. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around a bit the only way I see to open a browser from an RN app is using the Linking or LinkingIOS API. The question then is, how to enable your Webview to use that API. Here are two possible solutions:

1) Register your own URL Scheme that is handled by your app. E.g. myApp://this/is/a/link.html. Then handle all incoming events for that scheme and make corresponding calls to the API. Registering a scheme is easy and works very well. That seems like the most robust method to me.

2) Use a library that lets the Webview directly talk to it's paren view. E.g. https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge.
Then you put a little JS code in your page that onClick sends the link URLs to the parent view, that then calls the API. I have used that project a while ago and it work like a charm until one RN upgrade that I needed broke it. But it's still under active development so you should be fine.